# Unable to locate output folder on Ubuntu 22.04 MagiskOnWSA

Tags: windows, android, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install the google playstore on ubuntu with [this](https://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-install-google-play-store-on-windows-11-3049609/) guide.
After having successfully downloaded all packages i should now be able to copy and install the modified build.
Unfortunately, `cd MagiskOnWSALocal/output` gives me an error.

So how can I solve this problem?

I tried to install the output folder seperately, but what I've gotten from that seems to be having nothing to do with what I'm searching for..

[image: Screenshot]

Please ask if aything in my question is unclear, I'm totally new to Ubuntu as you could surely tell because of my very basic question.

Comment: This does not seam to be a Ubuntu related issue - You should ask this in a Android related forum

Comment: The tutorial is for Windows OS running a modified Windows Subsystem for Android (WSA). The part where it uses Linux is just to build a modified WSA, thus I'm not sure if it's even possible to run WSA on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's a bit of a misunderstanding in your question.  It seems that you think that the tutorial will allow you to run:

- Google Play Store

  - On Ubuntu

    - On WSL

      - On Windows

Whereas what is really happening is that the tutorial:

- Uses Ubuntu

  - On WSL

    - On Windows
  - to build a modified Windows Subsystem for Android

    - that will run the Google Play Store

With that in mind, using Ubuntu on WSL to build software is, according to our Meta discussions, on-topic here, regardless of what software is being built. So I'm going to attempt to answer your question, or at least point you in the right direction.

Your screenshot (err, [don't do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11810933)) starts off in the wrong directory (the home/`~` directory), which you seem to realize since you try to find the correct directory.  But you don't actually show the two most important things:

- The output of the `./run.sh` script
- The `ls` (list) of the directories you checked.

First, try:

```
cd ~/MagiskOnWSALocal
ls
```

See what directories are there.  If you have a `scripts` directory, but not an `output`, then something probably went wrong in the build step.

The best solution at that point would probably be to start over - Delete the entire MagiskOnWSALocal directory, `git clone` again, and this time pay close attention to the results of `./run.sh`.

Hopefully something in the output there should show went wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much!